# Bingsearch returning 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, search-engine, bing

I have written this code;

```
import bingsearch
bingsearch.API_KEY='mykey'
r = bingsearch.request("JohnDalton")
r.status_code
r[0]['Description']
print r[0]['Url']
```

This is th bingsearch.py file

```
import requests
import urllib2

URL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/SearchWeb/Web?Query=%(query)s&$top=50&$format=json'
API_KEY = 'mykey'

def request(query, **params):
    r = requests.get(URL % {'query': query}, auth=('', API_KEY))
    return r.json['d']['results']
```

As i mentioned in the title it gives me an instancemethod error. How should i fix this?

Comment: Your `request` function returns an item in the returned json, I'm quite sure your `r.status_code` expects the return value of `requests.get`

Comment: So what is happening, can you run the code yourself

Comment: What line is the error on? `__getitem__` is called whenever you do `foo[x]`. So, either `r`, `r[0]`, `r.json`, or `r.json['d']` is an instance method.

Comment: i get an error 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Barker was spot on earlier.

You need to change your line `return r.json['d']['results']` into `return r.json()['d']['results']`.

You should really do proper error checking on your `requests.get` result and on the JSON returned. It might not contain the items you expect and it will then raise a `KeyError`.

For the request errors you might want to check the [request documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) which has some basic starting points for possible exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. For that. Now i get an error 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'. I have never gotten this error.

Comment: @user2626758 it's an issue with the JSON you are passing to it, you should open a new question for this.